# Why isn't conformance implied by conforming the preexisting properties of the same name to the required types?

Tags: swift

Here is a playground that you can copy verbatim:

```
import UIKit

public final class TV {
    public let brightness: Mutating<Lumens>
    public let volume: Mutating<Decibels>
    init() {
        self.brightness=Mutating<Lumens>()
        self.volume=Mutating<Decibels>()
    }
}
public struct Lumens {}
public struct Decibels {}
public final class Mutating<T> {}

public protocol TVSpec {
    var brightness: LumensSpec & MutatingSpec { get }
    var volume: DecibelsSpec & MutatingSpec { get }
}
public protocol LumensSpec {}
public protocol DecibelsSpec {}
public protocol MutatingSpec {}

extension TV: TVSpec {}   // Error: Type 'TV' does not conform to protocol 'TVSpec'
extension Mutating: LumensSpec where T == Lumens {}
extension Mutating: DecibelsSpec where T == Decibels {}
extension Mutating: MutatingSpec {}
```

Once you do, I expect like myself you'll see the error. It's that type `TV` does not conform to protocol `TVSpec`.

Am I missing something here because `TV's` properties have the same name as those in `TVSpec` and extensions have been added to make `TV's` properties' types conform to the required types in `TVSpec`, so why is this failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> extensions have been added to make TV's properties' types conform to the required types

Not so. The protocol says:

```
var brightness: LumensSpec & MutatingSpec { get }
```

The class says:

```
public let brightness: Mutating<Lumens>
```

Those types don't match. And so too for the other property.

Comment: But extensions have been added to make `Mutating<Lumens>` conform to both `LumensSpec` and `MutatingSpec`, so why aren't they be treated that way?

Comment: Because a protocol doesn't give you _guidelines_ about types; it tells you _what to say_. You would have to type `brightness` as `LumensSpec & MutatingSpec` (and so too for the other property). You must write what the protocol told you to write, not something else.